# How to return a value after ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to return a ajax call value to other function. Code shown below

script

```
var obj2 = ajax_call();
    function ajax_call() {
    var obj3;   
    $.post("action.php",{action: 'view_style_code_action',style_val: v},function(data,status){
        obj3 = $.parseJSON(data);
    });
    return(obj3);
    }
    console.log(obj2+'test');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function ajax_call() {
    return $.post("action.php",{action: 'view_style_code_action',style_val: v},function(data,status){            
        return data;
    });

    }

    var obj2 = ajax_call();
    console.log(obj2+'test');
```

Comment: you can't get a return from a promise since it is asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

AJAX returns result in future (that's why it is asynchronous). Since JavaScript runs in a single thread, you cannot return a value immediately.

You need to understand jQuery's [Promise API](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) instead, which `$.post` already supports.

Modify your code a bit to leverage the power of promises in your code.

```
function ajax_call() {
  return $.post("action.php", {action: 'view_style_code_action',style_val: v})
}

ajax_call()
  .then(function(data) {
    // Do the parsing here
    var obj3 = $.parseJSON(data);

    // Do rest of your work here.
    ...
  });
```

Comment: how can i reuse obj3 value in the other function. If i want, i have to call again same ajax right? How to avoid the same ajax call repeatedly?

Comment: oh no, update your coding pattern to follow the asynchronous way

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/5836034 this should give you a better explanation

Comment: @Rijo: Pass the value of `obj3` from within `.then` to your other function, and then do whatever you want.